# Shapiro-Wilk Test Table gives no data in p value

Tags: normality-assumption

[image]

As you can see there is no figures in the Shapiro-Wilk test for the NONE hope level. Is this because the group level (2) is too small?

Comment: We can't see your data, but any two values are consistent with being drawn from a normal distribution. I have 42 and 666. Are they consistent with a normal distribution of unknown mean and SD? Absolutely. (If this doesn't answer the question, please show data, not just results.)

Comment: People usually are sympathetic to claims of desperation, urgency and the like, but they won't secure faster, better or more help. It's good, specific, concrete questions that make answers more likely, together with good presentation, including grammar, spelling and punctuation

Answer (score 1):

Guessing from your picture, for level NONE sample size is only 2, so Shapiro-Wilk test is not applicable because (as stated in original [paper](https://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/52/3-4/591) by Shapiro and Wilk) minimal sample size should be at least n = 3.

Additionally, for small sample sizes normality test are quite powerless. You can find more information [here](http://endometabol.com/?page=article&article_id=3505).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's what I was wondering, if my n value was too small for the test, but I couldn't seem to find an answer to this.

Comment: *No* test can determine information about shape in a location-scale family from two observations; you can get essentially any shape to fit them by choosing a corresponding location and scale. It's nothing to do with the Shapiro-Wilk test in particular.